# simple_form has_many through unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I'm having a little trouble setting up my simple for for create/update. Here's the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for( setup_menu(@menu) ) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description %>

<%= f.association :recipes %>

<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here are the three models:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :recipes, through: :courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes,
    reject_if: :all_blank

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses,
    reject_if: :all_blank
end
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :menus, through: :courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :menus 
end
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :menu
    belongs_to  :recipe
end
```

And here is the params definition from the menus_controller:

```
    def menu_params
      params.require(:menu).permit(:user_id, :name, :description, :recipe_ids, :course_ids, :courses, :recipes,
        recipes_attributes: [:id, :recipe_id, :_destroy],     courses_attributes: [:id, :recipe_id, :menu_id, :_destroy]
      )
    end
```

I keep getting an unpermitted parameter error on the recipe_ids.

```
Started PATCH "/menus/1" for ::1 at 2015-10-01 20:54:56 -0500
Processing by MenusController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"i/7E27BWul9trszURDu1z8PtsHaG54byG9JOlEp3mn2oQZVveM2mSP4XTLzjWKAK+BNvwoi/pqBbQPrPTcnaDw==", "menu"=>{"name"=>"Menu 1", "description"=>"First test menu", "recipe_ids"=>["", "1", "3", "4"]}, "
commit"=>"Update Menu", "id"=>"1"}
  Menu Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "menus".* FROM "menus" WHERE "menus"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: recipe_ids
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/menus/1
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

I'm sure it is something simple I've missed. I have been scratching my head for a whole day on this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it was something simple. This takes care of the whole problem.

```
params.require(:menu).permit(:user_id, :name, :description, { :recipe_ids => [] } )
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to your answer, there are a bunch of issues with your structure.

---

**Object**

You're calling `setup_menu` in your view; this should *at least* be called in your controller (unless you're using a partial... even then it should be passed as a local var).

```
<%= simple_form_for @menu do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
   <%= f.input :name %>
   <%= f.input :description %>

   <%= f.association :recipes %>

   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This has to be backed up with the appropriate controller action. Again, if you're using this in the likes of a `partial`, you'll be able to assign the action at the same time you're defining `@menu`:

```
#app/controllers/menus_controller.rb
class MenusController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @menu = setup_menu x
   end
end
```

---

**Associative Data**

Because you're using a `has_many :recipes` association, you should be able to set `:recipes` in your strong params. Failing that, your `recipe_ids` should be okay, but I think your encapsulation in parentheses is incorrect:

```
params.require(:menu).permit(:user_id, :name, :description, recipe_ids: [])
```

As an aside, if you had a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship set up, you'll be able to pass `recipes` as follows:

```
params.require(:menu).permit(:user, :name, :description, :recipes)
```

I see no reason why this would not work for your `has_many :through`

---

**Definitions**

Finally, you should be able to set multiple definitions in your model for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
#app/models/menu.rb
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :recipes, through: :courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes, :courses, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

One of the most important, and simple, ways of keeping your code efficient is to make it readable. Above is an example of this - [repeating yourself unnecessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) not only clutters your code, but prevents efficient management.

Comment: My apologies. I should have mentioned that the form above is a partial embedded in either new or edit. Everything I have read indicates that has_and_belongs_to_many is not a best practice approach in Rails 4. I'm not sure what you mean by "repeating yourself unnecessarily" in this case. What is repeated?

Comment: The unnecessary repeats were the multiple `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: In regards the form - how is it embedded? It looked standalone for me